# TypeCasting IndexedColorMap to ColorMap

Tags: scala, geotrellis

I have a code which gets the colormap of an image(*.tif).

`val geotiff = SinglebandGeoTiff(abcd.tif)`

`val colorMap1 = geotiff.options.colorMap`

Now colorMap1 is of type IndexedColorMap.

Is there a way to convert or typecast colormap1 to ColorMap(geotrellis.raster.render.ColorMap) , because my whole code is based on ColorMap and not on IndexedColorMap

Answer (score 1):

`IndexedColorMap` extends `IntColorMap` which extends `ColorMap` so they are compatible. But it looks like `geotiff.options.colorMap` is returning `Option[IndexedColourMap]` not `IndexedColorMap`. So you can do this:

```
val defaultColorMap: ColorMap = ???
val colorMap1: ColorMap = geotiff.options.colorMap.getOrElse(defaultColorMap)
```

See online for other ways to process `Option` values in Scala in a clean, functional way.

Comment: I did change the code as you said but it's still showing the same error:

```type mismatch```

```[error]  found   : Option[geotrellis.raster.render.IndexedColorMap]```

```[error]  required: geotrellis.raster.render.ColorMap```


```[error]   val colorMap1:ColorMap = geotiff.options.colorMap```

Comment: I am  trying to extract the colormap of the image in ```geotiff``` variable and use it in further codes. Setting a defaultColorMap won't help me in first case.
On top of it  ```Option``` values won't help me here because i already have a returning value i.e IndexedColorMap, i want to convert it. 
getOrElse() is used only when there is a chance for an empty return.

Comment: If the function is returning `Option` then there is a chance of an empty return and your code should really allow for this. But if you are happy with handling an exception in this case you can just call `get` rather than `getOrElse`.